# Threaded comments order problem

Tags: comments

While working with Drupal 7 we've got a problem, I'm not sure if it's a known bug or our personal issue. Anyway, I couldn't find such an issue while searching.

The issue is actually about order of threaded comments. Once activated, the order of comment answers goes wrong. For example (every next post is an answer to a previous post):

```
|| original comment
   || first answer
      || second answer
         ...
            || 12th answer
               ||13th answer (at this point is alright)
               **! here starts the problem**
                  || 15th comment
                     || 19th comment
                        || 18th comment
                           || 17th comment
                              || 16th comment
                                 || 20th comment
                                    || 14th comment
```

We first thought that it's our theme issue, but it's reproducible in Bartik as well. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.